# Liferay 6.2 EE Trial License Renewal

Tags: liferay

I am trying to register the current Liferay EE trial license provided by Liferay, but i keep getting corrupt license error.

Currently liferay is providing license for version 7.0 DE,But i want trial development license for 6.2 EE. I also tried sending an email to liferay sales.

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to contact Liferay, which you already did, since the 6.2 EE portal subscription won't be actively sold anymore. 6.2 EE is almost 3 years old now and will have one year [premium support](https://www.liferay.com/subscription-services/end-of-service-life/liferay-portal) left over. So depending on your project you'll need to make the right choice and act fast if 6.2 EE is needed (I thought subscription sales of 6.2 are ending in september 2016).